# Why aren't images from local url's opening in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

My react app contains a form in which the user submits an image file. I wanted to store the path of the image submitted locally where the browser has access to it, so I used URL.createObjectUrl to create a URL for the file. The code for that is:

```
handleImageChange(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const path = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        this.setState({ imageFile: path });
    }
```

This works correctly, and the URL is something like blob:http://localhost:3000/f2c6f9d4-ac80-4f18-94d9-8985c26001aa
Then I post that url to a backend flask route, in which it gets inserted into my sql database. Now, I want to display that image that was posted. I've successfully selected it from the database and have it in the correct component where it needs to be displayed. I used the slice method to remove "blob:" from the url and I display the image with the following code

```
<img src={props.flashcard.image_url} />
```

props.flashcard.image_url = http://localhost:3000/f2c6f9d4-ac80-4f18-94d9-8985c26001aa when I print it in the console just before displaying it, so I know that it is not an issue with moving states between components because I have what I want. The output is the standard tiny image icon, obviously not displaying my image at all. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or have any suggestions? Let me know if you need more info. Thank you.
edit:
I've also tried using the name of the image as the value to store in the database to be opened after. The code for that is here:

```
handleImageChange(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file.name)
        const path = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        this.setState({ imageFile: file.name });
    }
```

Comment: You need to use the file name you saved it as in the back end.

Comment: @Unmitigated I just changed the value i send to the backend from the path to the name of the file and that still provided the same result. Ive edited the end of the question to demonstrate my attempt

Answer (score 0):

In react you need to import the local images, external images you can use as usual.
like that:

```
import MyImage from './thumbnail.webp';
```

**local img:**

```
  <img src={MyImage} alt="horse" />
```

**external img:**

```
<img src="https://bobbyhadz.com/images/blog/react-prevent-multiple-button- 
        clicks/thumbnail.webp"/>
```

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-import-image

If you want a changeable src, use dinamic import. for example:

```
 import React, {useState} from "react"

const YourComponent = (props) => {

  const {changeImg,setChangeImg} = useState(false);
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  useEffect(()=>{
    try {(async()=>{
      const src=props.flashcard.image_url//bring your img src here(by fetch or explicitly);
      const response = await import(src);//dynamic import 
      setImg(response.default);
         })();
       } catch (err) {}
     },[props.flashcard])
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>setChangeImg(!changeImg)}>change 
          image</button>
      <img alt="" className="img-responsive" src={image} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok so how do I import from a stateful object.

Comment: I've tried this import Image from ``${props.flashcard.image_url}`` and that brought error

Comment: it won't let me show it but I have ${props.flashcard.image_url} surrounded in backticks

Comment: @ thealchemist7777 i edited my solution. I checked the dinamic import and it worked. I think you should try it.

Comment: Tell me if it was useful and mark it.